# How to make a while loop that stops once one of tree condition is fulfilled

Tags: python, while-loop

it's a school project, I got this so far:

```
 while act != "AT" or act == "FU" or act =="OBJ": 
        act = input("AT pour attaquer, FU pour tenter de fuire, OBJ pour utiliser un objet")
        if act != "AT" or act == "FU" or act =="OBJ":
            print("Option invalide, veuillez réessayer")
```

It's supposed to ask a question over and over again until its answered properly but so far the only working option is AT

Comment: Why have you used one not-equal (`!=`) and two equal (`==`)?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want act to be one of `FU` OR `OBJ` and it shouldn't be `AT`

```
while True:
     act = input("AT pour attaquer, FU pour tenter de fuire, OBJ pour utiliser un objet")
     if act != 'AT' and act in ['FU', 'OBJ']:
           break
```

Comment: What's the point to first compare that `act != 'AT' then comparing it as `act in ['FU', 'OBJ']` ?

Comment: Anyhow if act is in `['FU', 'OBJ']` then it will automatically not equal to 'AT' ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi no point, just OP clearance

Comment: @assume_irrational_is_rational Sorry I didn't go on for a while, to answer you, I was tying to make the loop stop if either AT, FU or OBJ were used, at first I did
while act == "AT" or act == "FU" or act =="OBJ":
But it didn't work so I tried random compareasons before asking here